Can angles be defined by norms that are not induced by inner products?
Can angles be (well-)defined in a normed vector space where the parallelogram law does not hold? In other words, if the norm is not induced by an inner product in a normed space (say $L^1$ space), can angles still be (well-)defined in that space?

Maybe the paper "Angles in normed spaces" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06938.pdf contains something in this direction.
